# Keras: Constraint linking input and output

Tags: python, tensorflow, constraints, keras

Is there a way in which we can enforce constraint on the prediction of sequences?

Say, if my modeling is as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(150, input_shape=(n_timesteps_in, n_features)))
model.add(RepeatVector(n_timesteps_in))
model.add(LSTM(150, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_features, activation='linear')))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
```

Can I somehow capture the constraint that `model.pred(x) <= x`

The [docs](https://keras.io/constraints/) shows that we can add constraints to the network weights. However, they do not mention how to map relationship or constraints between input and output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keras provides an easy way to handle such trivial constraints. We could write `out = Minimum()([out, input_tensor])`

Complete example

```
import keras
from keras.layers.merge import Maximum, Minimum
from IPython.display import SVG
from keras.utils.vis_utils import model_to_dot

n_timesteps_in = 20 
n_features=2
input_tensor = keras.layers.Input(shape = [n_timesteps_in, n_features])

out = keras.layers.LSTM(150)(input_tensor)
out = keras.layers.RepeatVector(n_timesteps_in)(out) 
out = keras.layers.LSTM(150, return_sequences=True)(out)
out = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(n_features))(out)

out = Minimum()([out, input_tensor])
model = keras.Model(input_tensor, out )
SVG(model_to_dot(model,  show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True, rankdir='HB').create(prog='dot', format='svg'))
```

Here's the network structure of the model. It shows how the input and the output are used to compute clamped output.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Never heard of it.... but there are quite a few ways you can implement that yourself using a functional API model and custom functions.

Below, there is a possible answer to this, but first, is this really the best to do??

If you're trying to create an autoencoder, you should not care about limiting the outputs. Otherwise, your model will not really learn much.

Maybe the best to do is simply normalizing the inputs first (between -1 and +1), and using the `tanh` activation at the end.

#### Funtional API model to preserve the input:

```
inputTensor = Input(n_timesteps_in, n_features)

out = LSTM(150, input_shape=)(inputTensor)
out = RepeatVector(n_timesteps_in)(out) #this line sounds funny in your model...
out = LSTM(150, return_sequences=True)(out)
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_features))(out)
out = Activation(chooseOneActivation)(out)

out = Lambda(chooseACustomFunction)([out,inputTensor])

model = Model(inputTensor,out)
model.compile(...)
```

### Custom limit options

There are infinite ways of doing this, here are some examples that may or may not be what you need. But from this you are free to develop anything similar.

The options below limits the individual outputs to the respective individual inputs. But you may prefer to use all outputs confined to the maximum input instead.

If so, use this below: `maxInput = max(originalInput, axis=1, keepdims=True)`

#### 1 - A simple stretched 'tanh':

You can simply define both top and bottom limits by using a `tanh` (that ranges from -1 to +1) and multiplying it by the inputs.

Use the `Activation('tanh')` layer, and the following custom function in the `Lambda` layer:

```
import keras.backend as K

def stretchedTanh(x):

    originalOutput = x[0]
    originalInput = x[1]

    return K.abs(originalInput) * originalOutput
```

I'm not totally sure this will be a healthy option. If the idea is to create an autoencoder, this model will easily find a solution of outputing all `tanh` activations as close to 1 as possible, without really looking at the inputs.

#### 2 - Modified 'relu'

First, you could simply `clip` your outputs based on the inputs, changing a **relu** activation. Use the `Activation('relu')(out)` in your model above, and the following custom function in the `Lambda` layer:

```
def modifiedRelu(x):
    negativeOutput = (-1) * x[0] #ranging from -infinite to 0
    originalInput = x[1] 

    #ranging from -infinite to originalInput
    return negativeOutput + originalInput #needs the same shape between input and output
```

This may have a downside when everything goes above the limit and backpropagation gets unable to return. (A problem that might happen with 'relu').

#### 3 - Half linear, half modified tanh

In this case, you don't need the `Activation` layer, or you can use it as `'linear'`.

```
import keras.backend as K

def halfTanh(x):

    originalOutput = x[0]
    originalInput = x[1]  #assuming all inputs are positive

    #find the positive outputs and get a tensor with 1's at their positions
    positiveOutputs = K.greater(originalOuptut,0)
    positiveOutputs = K.cast(positiveOutputs,K.floatx())

    #now the 1's are at the negative positions
    negativeOutputs = 1 - positiveOutputs

    tanhOutputs = K.tanh(originalOutput) #function limited to -1 or +1
    tanhOutputs = originalInput * sigmoidOutputs #raises the limit from 1 to originalInput

    #use the conditions above to select between the negative and the positive side
    return positiveOutputs * tanhOutputs + negativeOutputs * originalOutputs
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking a lot of time and effort into this post. I found a trivial way to handle this simple `minimum` constraint in Keras. Posted it in my answer. I think your approach can be useful in a wider variety of constraints. Many thanks :)

Comment: Your answer is equivalent to the 'relu' case. There is a risk you will get "nan" values during training, in a case where all outputs are bigger than the inputs. This is highly probable, though, since the limit value is exactly the value you want to reach.

Comment: Thanks :) I think the answer is worth the bounty :) So, giving it!